# React Navigation Drawer Position

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-drawer

I am using React Navigation's Drawer from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer,  I would like to give the starting position of drawer below the header, but I have no idea how I can achieve this. I've been looking at the documentation from reactnavigation.org, but can't really find any hints.

Answer (score 0):

It will by default comes below the header, you can try something like this in your index.android.js or index.ios.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, BackAndroid, StatusBar,} from 'react-native';
import {
  NavigationActions,
  addNavigationHelpers,
  StackNavigator,
  DrawerNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';


import LandingScreen from 'src/screens/landingScreen';
import Login from 'src/screens/login'
import SignUp from 'src/screens/signUp'
import ForgotPassword from 'src/screens/forgotPassword'
import Dashboard from 'src/screens/dashboard'
import UserProfile from 'src/screens/userProfile'

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard:{
    path:'/',
    screen:Dashboard,
  },
  UserProfile:{
    path:'/'
    screen:UserProfile
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
  headerMode: 'screen',
});

const routesConfig = {
  Landing:{screen:LandingScreen},
  Login: { screen: Login },
  SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
  ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
  Drawer:{screen:Drawer}
};

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(routesConfig, {
  initialRouteName: 'Drawer'
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Riduk', () => AppNavigator);
```